Where am I going wrong in voltage equation of Capacitor in \$RC\$ circuit?
Where am I going wrong in voltage equation of Capacitor in \$RC\$ circuit?
An initially charged capacitor with voltage \$V_0\$ is connected in series with a Switch and a Resistor. I was able to derive the time varying current equation in the circuit , where the switch is closed at \$t=0\$.It is given by
$$I(t)=\frac{V_0}{R}e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}$$
But now I tried to find \$V_c(t)\$ which is the voltage across the capacitor using: $$I(t)=C\frac{dV_c(t)}{dt} \Rightarrow V_c(t)=\frac{1}{C}\int_{-\infty}^tI(t)dt=V_0+\frac{1}{C}\int_0^t \frac{V_0}{R}e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}dt$$
So we get $$V_c(t)=V_0+V_0\left(1-e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}\right)$$
Now my doubt is, as \$t \to \infty\$, I am getting \$V_c(t)=2V_0\$, How is this possible?
Is not the Capacitor getting discharged?

You've simply flipped the sign of the current through the capacitor:

(Please excuse the crude diagram.)
This means that:
$$
I_C(t) = -I_R(t) = C\frac{dV_c(t)}{dt} \\
\Rightarrow I_R(t) = \frac{V_0}{R}e^\frac{-t}{RC} = -C\frac{dV_c(t)}{dt}\\
\Rightarrow ... \Rightarrow V_C(t) = V_0 - V_0 (1 - e^\frac{-t}{RC}) = V_0 e^\frac{-t}{RC}
$$
This also makes intuitive sense: The higher the positive current through the resistor, the faster the capacitor discharges, which means that the derivative of its voltage is negatively proportional to the resistor current.

From -\$t=\infty \text{ to } 0\$, charge flows into the capacitor and so the current can be considered positive. After the switch is closed charge flows out of the capacitor and so is considered negative. The following circuit diagram represents your equation over the entire integration interval.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Clearly the current reverses in the capacitor so the correct equation is
$$
v_C(t)=V_0-V_0(1-e^{\frac{t}{\tau}})
$$
